# document.DocumentNode.QuerySelectorAll does not retrun anything

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I try to access the "div.prod_inner" on the following homepage (see image) for web scraping.
I use the HtmlAgilityPack and the code works on another homepage and also on `"div.lay_main"`  returning one element.

[image: Screen dump from the page I try to scrape]

This is the code I use (C#):

```
var productHTMLElements = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.prod_inner);
```

I also tried with

```
var productHTMLElements = document.DocumentNode.QuerySelectorAll("div.prod_inner");
```

and `".prod_inner"` and `"prod_inner"` and it does not work either.

I expect the code to fill an array with all the products found on the page that are of class. But the array remains empty.

I am all new to web scraping. What do I do wrong, and how do I do it right?

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask a good question with a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You also have syntax errors in your first code (missing `"`.)

Comment: Check if you code is perhaps running before the page has completely been loaded or rendered. Also lots of sites these days are dynamic and will update / add content after the initial page load. For this purpose there are good libraries like Puppeteer, see e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gWU4XmM96To

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually using HtmlAgilityPack you are using a library called [Hazz](https://github.com/atifaziz/Hazz) that extends HAP.

I am not familiar with that, but using XPATH should work.

```cs
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//div[contains(@class, ""prod_inner"")]");
```

Comment: Thank you for swift responses. I realized that the problem was, that I tried to access a web page that required login and I thought I was in because I had logged on via my regular browser. I finally got access (my own web page by the way) using step by step screen dumps using Selenium.